# Excel VBA .saveas premission denied with onedrive

Tags: excel, vba, office365, onedrive

I've created a macro to get data from active workbook, copy it into a new one and save new file. Whole code worked perfect until I changed Office to 365 with Onedrive on my computer.
When I run this macro, I get error 1004: Premission denied in macro below

```
Sub create_new()

    Dim SheetI As Worksheet
    Dim SheetO As Worksheet
    Dim BookO As Workbook
    Dim BookI As Workbook
    Dim row As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim path As String
    Dim brng As Range
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") & "\path\"
    If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir path
    path = path & _
        Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"
    If Dir(path) <> "" Then Kill path
    Set BookI = ThisWorkbook
    Set BookO = Workbooks.Add
    With BookO
        BookO.Sheets.Add.Name = "Name"
        Set SheetO = BookO.Sheets("Name")
        SheetO.Cells(1, 1).Value = "1"
        SheetO.Cells(1, 2).Value = "2"
        SheetO.Cells(1, 3).Value = "3"
        SheetO.Columns("A:H").AutoFit
        SheetO.Range("a1:h1").Font.Bold = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    
    Set dict = SubTotals(BookI)
    For Each SheetI In BookI.Sheets
         If SheetI.Name <> "Dane" Then
            For row = 10 To SheetI.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row Step 1
                If i <= row Then
                    If SheetI.Cells(row, 2).Value = "Oprysk" Then
                        If Not found Then found = True
                        i = row
                        If SheetI.Cells(row, 2).MergeCells Then i = row + SheetI.Cells(row, 2).MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1
                        With BookO
                            Range(SheetI.Cells(row, 1), SheetI.Cells(i, 1)).Copy
                            SheetO.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                            Range(SheetI.Cells(row, 5), SheetI.Cells(i, 8)).Copy
                            SheetO.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                            SheetI.Cells(2, 2).Copy
                            SheetO.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                            SheetI.Cells(3, 5).Copy
                            SheetO.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                            SheetO.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SearchDict(dict, SheetO.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Value)
                            If i <> row Then
                                For l = 1 To 8 Step 1
                                    If l <> 6 And l <> 7 Then
                                        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                                        Range(SheetO.Cells(Rows.Count, l).End(xlUp), SheetO.Cells(Rows.Count, l).End(xlUp).Offset(i - row, 0)).Merge
                                        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                                    End If
                                Next l
                            End If
                            
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            Next row
         End If
    Next SheetI
    If found Then
        Set brng = Range(SheetO.Cells(1, 1), SheetO.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2))
        With BookO
            brng.BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin
            brng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            brng.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .SaveAs path
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
        MsgBox "File saved in path: " & path
    Else
        With BookO
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            BookO.Close
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
        Kill path
        MsgBox "Data not found"
    End If
        
End Sub
```

So basicly I check here if the path and file exists. If not, its created. I save the new workbook for the first time when its formated but before data is copied. Secondly its saved when the data is copied and this second attempt to save workbook fails with error above. Why I was able to overwrite this workbook when I didnt use Onedrive and now, when I do it shows me the error?

Comment: Have you tried saving locally? Does that error?

Comment: If the workbook has already been saved, then you only need to call `Book0.Save`  It would help to indicate exactly where your code is failing.

Comment: @SolarMike, locally it works just fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams, as said above it worked fine locally and Im wondering why I get error while using OneDrive. However, I can just .saveas after copying data. It will also work with OneDrive.

Comment: What line of code exactly fails? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, it fails with line .SaveAs path at the bottom of code. I've tried to debug it, but everything seems to be fine. The problem is that there is no premission to overwrite the file.

Comment: Is the file read only?